# The difference boolean doesn't seem to work on a specific area

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am trying to build a pc in blender and I just updated my blender to 2.91 but the boolean modifier doesn't seem to work as expected on a specific area.I am attaching a video below

https://streamable.com/ovvr7a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boolean modifier relies on correctly set normals. Check if your normals are all facing outwards by checking "Face Orientation" in the Viewport Overlays menu:

[image: Overlays Menu]

All the outward faces should be blue. If an object has incorrect normals, you can select all of its faces (<kbd>A</kbd>) in edit mode, and `Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside` (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)

Comment: Still not working :C .. I checked the normals and they were as they should be..Blue outside and red inside. Though it was looking like the two faces were overlapping on other areas but it is probably because of the thinness of the case. Should I give you the blend file??

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much.. :D :D.. I found a way around..The normals was only the problem so I created a new mesh and then I combined it with the case and now its working perfectly.. Once again thank you very much