# Bool tool leaves parts after slicing

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can I cut out the slice(bite) without leaving any teeths?

1. Select teeth
2. Select fish
3. Bool Tool - Slice
4. Delete the slice

[image: picture]

I can't see any face orientation problems (shown in screenshot above)
I tried before slicing:

- Deleting everything possible eg. rigs, poses, vertex groups
- `Ctrl+A` Apply - All transforms
- `Shift+N` Recalculate Normals

[image]

Similar problem though not solving my case: [The difference boolean doesn't seem to work on a specific area](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212552/the-difference-boolean-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-a-specific-area)

Comment: I would say it is an issue of topology (too small or ugly after cut). Also try to use regular Boolean Modifier, because I'm not sure BooTool can use "Exact" solver. If you want to let us see your issue closer attach simplified blend. Use https://blend-exchange.com copy-paste given code into your Q.

Comment: @vklidu Thank you, tried regular without success. Attached the simplified file 13MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Boolean Modifier* (instead *Bool Tool*) with **Exact** solver, plus enable **Self** - intersection, because those "red" teeth are overlapping.

[image]

... or in edit mode select all and with pivot point set to *Individual Origins* scale all teeth a bit so they don't overlap.

[image]

... and enable under *Data Properties > Normals >* **Auto Smooth** if you want to fix shading around edges.

Also I would highly suggest to use *Un-Subdivide* operator in edit mode, your topology is too dense. You can use Iterations up to 4 for shark and 4-6 for teeth. Result is pretty much the same with much lighter file and faster calculation. To make it smooth add Subdivision Modifier only for Shark before Boolean.

[image]